# I keep getting a "subscript out of bounds" error when trying to install ggTimeSeries package in R - how do I install the package?

Tags: r, installation, package, subscript, ggtimeseries

I'm trying to make a calendar heatmap, and for that I'm using the ggplot_calendar_heatmap function from ggTimeSeries. I have had repeated errors when trying to install this package and the data.frame package.

Here is my code:

```
> install.packages("ggTimeSeries", dependencies = TRUE)
```

It proceeds to try a bunch of urls, and then it give me this error message:

```
    Error in desc[1L, "Type"] : subscript out of bounds
    In addition: Warning message:
    In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : write error in extracting from zip file
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, all went fine. Maybe if you try setting `type = "source"`

Comment: I am getting this same error for every new package I've tried to install, not just this one. I will try that though.

Comment: When I do that I get a bunch of "installation of package ‘###’ had non-zero exit status" messages.

Comment: I get that error when the packages were installed prior to R 4.0. It's annoying to have to reinstall them one by one but it solves the problem.

Comment: (1) Is this windows, by chance? Have you installed Rtools with a space somewhere in the directory path? That has been a problem in the past with R, which is why (I believe) Rtools (and Rtools40) defaults to installing in `C:\Rtools\` and not under `C:\Program Files\Rtools\`. (2) What is the `data.frame` package? Do you mean `data.table`?

Comment: Also possible: do you have Rtools or R installed on a network drive?